# Append to the correct row in table which is generated automatically

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows. I try to add some content to every fifth  element in every row. The problem I'm facing is that every row or cell don't have a classname or id. So what I tried is to first add a classname to the fifth element and the append the new content. This works, but now in every fifth  element the same content is shown. What I'm I doing wrong?

**NOTE: The data which must be placed in the fifth element comes from a template engine which isn't important vfor this question.**

HTML (shortened for readabillity)

```
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
      <span class="gui-nowrap 0">....data from script below....</span><br>
      <span class="gui-nowrap value 0">....data from script below....</span>
     </td>
     <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
       <span class="gui-nowrap">....data from script below....</span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td>.... some content....</td>
     <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
      <span class="gui-nowrap 1">....data from script below....</span><br>
      <span class="gui-nowrap value 1">....data from script below....</span>
     </td>
     <td width="10%" class="gui-align-right">
       <span class="gui-nowrap">....data from script below....</span>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
  var counter = 0;
   $('tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
     var targetClass= counter++;
     $(this).html('<span class="gui-nowrap '+targetClass+'">{{ price }}</span><br/>
     <span class="gui-nowrap value '+targetClass+'">+ {{ value.price }}</span>').appendTo(targetClass);
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: You have same content, how do you expect different content to be?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha: changed the question. Forgot to mention that thanks for the heads up...

Comment: it looks like your doing something to every 6th element as well. what do you mean by the same content? your script should be giving you the same content but with different class names and price/value.price. are you getting the same price and value.price in every element?

Comment: @DeckerWBrower: Yes exactly... I get the same price/value.price in every element. I think the script loops over all the data and only uses the last data...

Comment: I'm thinking there's something going on with your template. can you post your full template with the javascript? it looks like you might be missing some steps in your loop. we need to see where price and value.price come from. you are probably referencing the same object in every iteration when you need to be looping the prices and values.

Comment: Without seeing the template, the price and value.price should be added by using something like: object[targetClass].price and object[targetClass].value.price. Right now, you loop with jquery, but how does the template engine know, which iteration you're at.